# How can I insert an 'insertion' inside a W_L-W_R mixing charged boson line?

Tags: tikz-feynman

I am trying to generate the following feynman diagram using tikz-feynman package

[image]

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{forest}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{feynmf}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\vertex [small, dot] (b) {};
\vertex [left=3cm of b, Gray!40!Black] (a) {$d_R$};
\vertex [right=3.0cm of b, Gray!40!Black] (c) {$u_R$};
\vertex [below=0.75cm of b] (d) {};
\vertex [small, dot, below=0.75cm of d] (e) {};
\vertex [right=2cm of e, NavyBlue] (f) {$e_L^-$};
\vertex [small, below=1.8cm of e] (g) {};
\diagram* {
(a) -- [fermion, Gray!40!Black, line width=0.35mm] (b) -- [fermion, Gray!40!Black, line width=0.35mm] (c),
(b) -- [charged boson, line width=0.35mm, OliveGreen, edge label=$W^-_R$] (d)-- [charged boson, line width=0.35mm, OliveGreen, edge label=$W^-_L$] (e),
(b) -- [boson, insertion=0.5, line width=0.35mm,  OliveGreen] (e), 
(e) -- [fermion, line width=0.35mm, NavyBlue] (f),
(e) -- [anti fermion, line width=0.35mm,  BrickRed, edge label=$\color{BrickRed}\nu_{eL}$] (g),
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

which is generating the following pic

[image]

Anybody has any solution? Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please make your example code compilable?

Comment: Thank you! I have corrected the code, should be compilable now.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider posting complete examples instead of code fragments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\vertex [small, dot, label=90:\tiny{$V+A$}] (b) {};
\vertex [left=3cm of b, Gray!40!Black] (a) {$d_\mathrm{R}$};
\vertex [right=3.0cm of b, Gray!40!Black] (c) {$u_\mathrm{R}$};
\vertex [small, dot, below=1.5cm of b, label=350:\tiny{$V-A$}, label=180:\small{$\color{BrickRed} \sum_{i}[U_{ei}\nu_{iL}+S_{ei}N^c_{iR}]$}] (e) {};
\path (b) -- (e) coordinate[midway] (d);
\vertex [right=2cm of e, NavyBlue] (f) {$e_\mathrm{L}^-$};
\vertex [small, below=1.8cm of e] (g) {};
\diagram* {
(a) -- [fermion, Gray!40!Black, line width=0.35mm] (b) -- [fermion, Gray!40!Black, line width=0.35mm] (c),
(b) -- [charged boson, line width=0.35mm, OliveGreen, edge label=$W^-_\mathrm{R}$] (d)--
[insertion=0,charged boson, line width=0.35mm, OliveGreen, edge label=$W^-_\mathrm{L}$] (e),
(e) -- [fermion, line width=0.35mm, NavyBlue] (f),
(e) -- [anti fermion, line width=0.35mm,  BrickRed, edge label=$\color{BrickRed}\nu_{eL}$] (g),
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Will correct it next time.